# How to create a polymorphic and additive init() function in C++?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, design-patterns, initialization

Suppose there is a simple hierarchy without multiple inheritance involved:

```
class base {
public:
    base() { /* */ }
    virtual void init() { /* */ }
};

class derived_a : public base {
public:
    derived_a() { /* */ }
    virtual void init() override { base::init(); /* local stuff to add */ }
};

class derived_b : public base {
public:
    derived_b() { /* */ }
    virtual void init() override { base::init(); /* local stuff to add */ }
};
```

Then the client code goes like

```
auto d_a = new derived_a{};
d_a->init();
```

I see two problems:

a) Repeating `base::init()` in every `derived_x::init()`

b) Repeating `derived_x::init()` every time a derived class object is created

Both can easily be forgotten, from my point of view.

I know that in `base::base{}`, you're `base`, not `derived_x`, by how virtual dispatch works in C++. But there is be a workaround, isn't there? Looks like a common problem that developers have faced many times already. What is (are) the possible solution(s)?

Comment: Two phase initialization is bad, just don't do this. You can add a protected constructor in your base class to do the common part of the initialization, and pass whatever argument you need from the derived class constructor.

Comment: This is what constructors do for you automatically.

Comment: If you add initialisation code to constructors, and do away with 2-phase initialisation by eliminating the `init()`, you will find that constructors do what you want - base class constructors are ALWAYS invoked before derived class constructors, when creating an instance of a derived class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can live with forcing the use of factory functions on your users, you can add a finalizer class template at the bottom of the hierarchy

```
template<typename T>
class base_finalizer : public T
{
    base_finalizer()
    {
        this->base::init();
        this->T::init();
    }
};

template<typename T>
auto make_base()
{
    return unique_ptr<T>(new base_finalizer<T>);
}
```

This also allows your base_finalizer to do some cleanup using the final dynamic type of the object if you need it.

That being said, always strive for being able to have your types available with simple value semantics.

Comment: @iksemyonov thanks. I'm actually using this in my project and it performs fairly well (I use it to finish `Base`'s `QThread` event handling before objects required by those events go out of scope when `Derived` is destroyed)

Comment: Aren't you expected to `moveToThread()` instead of subclassing `QThread`? Mean, I recall there are exceptions, but there has to be a grave reason to do so. Or are you not subclassing and I'm misreading?

Comment: @iksemyonov I do not subclass `QThread`. `Base` has a member `QThread worker` that does most of the work, but some events accept stateful functors/lambdas and those have references/pointers to `Derived`'s members. Thus I need to shut those down before I can destroy `Derived`.

Comment: Oh ok, need to draw it out on a piece of paper to fully grasp, but I get the general idea.

Comment: @iksemyonov yes, well. Looking back at it maybe I would've designed it a little differently, but it's pretty much set in stone now :)

Answer (score 2):

The idiomatic solution would be to have no `init` method at all. Everything that happens there should happen in some constructor (either of the `base` or `derived_*` classes or of the members that the `init` function would touch.

This way, it cannot be forgotten.

Comment: True, didn't occur to me that constructors are there exactly for that purpose.